# How can I create a button with an image?

Tags: html, css, button

I have an image that i want to use as a button on my page that links to other pages. I want to make it in a way that I can use small and large texts on it.

The image in question:

[image]

I have tried something but can go no where with it.

```
a {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/8Isga60.png);
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:30px 100px;
    height:20px;
    color:black;
    font-size:16px;

}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHHMb/)

Comment: There might be a solution for some length, but at some point an image will always be too small (because it is a fixed size).  You really should consider a pure CSS solution for the button (without image).  Just google "CSS button generator"

Comment: You should recreate the button in CSS instead of using a static image. That way it will size to whatever content is within it without distorting the style of the button.

Comment: The old-school method of doing this is: http://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors

Comment: css will not be able to incorporate the design that is in the image :(

Comment: Main requirement is the indent on the sides and the gloss at the bottom as you can see in the image. I have actually tried pure css but can not make the indent and the gloss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to split the image, as If you try to repeat it using it as a complete image, it will also repeat the rounded parts. So take the left and right, and a pixel from the center. See this answer for reference [Button using three (3) background images css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625401/button-using-three-3-background-images-css)

The old school version is something like using three classes for left and right and one for center with the repeating background.[Create button using 3 images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114182/create-button-using-3-images)

Now, as mentioned in the comments, unless you are completely decided on the background images part, a pure CSS solution will probably work better.

Comment: That approach is very 2005... we can be much more light-wight and flexible with pure CSS these days.

Comment: While I agree, the OP did not put an age restriction on the solution. Now, I updated the answer, as the old and cool new (and probably more efficient) options have been presented many times in other questions.

Comment: I will have to use the old school idea for now. Thanks @Ernesto

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you drop the image idea... that concept is very 2005.  With today's CSS you can easily recreate that image with pure CSS, which then is much more flexible.

If you Google "CSS button generator" you will find many online tools that help you with that... i.e. http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/

Here is an example I did in 10 seconds and just copied the CSS they provided... granted it is a little convoluted, but it certainly works:

```
<style type="text/css">
.classname {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #79bbff), color-stop(1, #378de5) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#79bbff', endColorstr='#378de5');
    background-color:#79bbff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:20px;
    border-top-left-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:20px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #84bbf3;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    width:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #528ecc;
}
.classname:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5), color-stop(1, #79bbff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#378de5', endColorstr='#79bbff');
    background-color:#378de5;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}</style>
```

Comment: We can probably drop most of those `-moz-*` and `-webkit-*` prefixes now (it's *so* 2009).

Comment: Sorry don't want a full CSS button, I need to use the design of the image. Thanks for the time.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - fully agreed.  Just copied/pasted straight from the website to show how quickly you can create a CSS button, with little knowledge of CSS.  But you are right, it should probably be cleaned up.

Comment: @user3771900 - You might want to talk to your designer then. A pure CSS solution can get you very close (as Nick R's solution shows) and is much, much, much more flexible.  Pure image solutions will break constantly and are a b***h to maintain.

Comment: @Steve I know Steve I am trying to pursue my designer to dump the image's design.

Answer (score 1):

You could almost do it in CSS3: **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vHHMb/7/)**

```
.btn {

    margin:10px;
    color:white;
    font-size:16px;
    border:4px solid #c5c7c9;
    border-radius: 50px 50px;
    display:inline-block;

    /* Drop shadow */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.68);
    -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.68);
    box-shadow:         1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.68);

    /* Gradient Background */

    background: rgb(78,186,234); /* Old browsers */

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(78,186,234,1) 0%, rgba(0,121,183,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(78,186,234,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,121,183,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(78,186,234,1) 0%,rgba(0,121,183,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(78,186,234,1) 0%,rgba(0,121,183,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(78,186,234,1) 0%,rgba(0,121,183,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(78,186,234,1) 0%,rgba(0,121,183,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4ebaea', endColorstr='#0079b7',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

    /* Button Sizes. */
    .btn.large {  padding:30px 60px; }
    .btn.small {   padding:10px 30px; }
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="btn large">my text here</a>      
<a href="#" class="btn small">my text here</a>
<a href="#" class="btn small">my text here long text goes here</a>
```

Comment: +1 - Very nice demo of how close you can get to the original design and how flexible it gets for long, short, tall content. Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a{
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/8Isga60.png) no-repeat center;
    ...
}
```

However it moves the button too. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHHMb/)

You should really look into CSS buttons instead of using images. Try [CSS Button Generator](http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the left & right padding, Why not separate the link and the text so it's easy to center the content?

(edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M9tre/2/) )

```
<p><a class="sol" href="http://imgur.com/8Isga60"><span>Does not work with larger text</span></a></p>

a.sol {
        background:url(http://i.imgur.com/8Isga60.png);
        display:inline-block;
        padding:30px 0px;
        width: 243px;
        height:20px;
        color:white;
        font-size:16px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```